# How to make another class object without new

Tags: php, laravel

I've made a function in class mail and created a function send() in it that is implemented in other class and I have passed Client object as an argument. I want to use Client object in person class directly without passing inside parameters and using new keyword  ?

```
Use Client;

class Mail
{
    public function letter()
    {
        send($user, Client $client);  
    }
}

class Person
{
    public function send($user, $client)
    {
        // code
    }
}
```

Comment: without using `new` keyword you want to use object ?

Comment: What is your actual goal is not clear

Comment: due to dependency .

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're describing.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: i am using a GuzzleHttp\Client in, I want to make its object in my Person class ,

Comment: It's unclear what youre asking here

Comment: If you would like to call class'es method without creating instance of that class, you can use static function. Then you can call ```MyClass::myMethod()```.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can do this like this. `(new Client)->urFuntion();`;

It still uses the `new`  behind the seen.

Comment: I have to make object Without using new basically its due to dependency injection .

Comment: @GoldSmith then pass the object in constructor.

Comment: Constructor of Class where I am implementing this method ?